# Cakephp routes prefix

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have 3 diferent layouts for my application related to diferent parts of content.
I vould like to define my url-s so they would have the part in the begining ex. "mypage.com/part1/controller/...". 
I don't know how to change routes to make this possible.

P.S. I don't want ordinary prefix routing where names of my controller actions would have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read below url

For CakePHP 2.x
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

For CakePHP 1.x
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Frank/2009/11/02/cakephp-s-routing-explained

Or

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin', 'manager'));

$this->connect("/{$prefix}/:plugin/:controller", array('action' => 'index', 'prefix' => $prefix, $prefix => true));
$this->connect("/{$prefix}/:plugin/:controller/:action/*", array('prefix' => $prefix, $prefix => true));
Router::connect("/{$prefix}/:controller", array('action' => 'index', 'prefix' => $prefix, $prefix => true));
Router::connect("/{$prefix}/:controller/:action/*", array('prefix' => $prefix, $prefix => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to integrate multiple prefix with routing in cakephp

In cakephp 2.x you have to go through following steps

1. go to the app/Config/core.php and add following lines Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin','manager'));
2. Now you have to write the routing for this go to the app/Config/routes.php add following lines
3. Router::connect("admin/:controller",array('action'=>'index','admin'=>true));
4. Router::connect("admin/:controller/:action/*",array('admin'=>true));
5. Router::connect("manager/:controller",array('action'=>'index','manager'=>true));
6. Router::connect("manager/:controller/:action",array('manager'=>true));

For more info refer following link 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html
http://miftyisbored.com/complete-tutorial-admin-routing-cakephp/