# I want to create multiple prefix in cakephp 2.8

Tags: cakephp, multiple-users

I am create web application in cakephp 2.8, i want more than 2 prefix in user.

example :

`http://localhost/project/admin,`

`http://localhost/project/employee,`

`http://localhost/project/customer`

please suggest me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy to integrate multiple prefix with routing in cakephp

In cakephp 2.x you have to go through following steps

go to the app/Config/core.php and add following lines

`Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin','manager'));`

Now you have to write the routing for this go to the app/Config/routes.php add following lines

```
Router::connect("admin/:controller",array('action'=>'index','admin'=>true));
Router::connect("admin/:controller/:action/*",array('admin'=>true));
Router::connect("manager/:controller",array('action'=>'index','manager'=>true));
Router::connect("manager/:controller/:action",array('manager'=>true));
```

Source: [Cakephp routes prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705107/cakephp-routes-prefix)

Comment: Got the Answer
app/Config/core.php
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin','manager'));